# Symfony Serializer and ArrayCollection to XML

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I am trying to use the Symfony Serializer to serialize a nested entity with Doctrine ArrayCollections to XML.

There are some problems i encounter:

1. ArrayCollections seem not to be serialized, is the symfony serializer capable to do this?
   Or do i need to tweak it?
2. The XMLEncoder doesnt support Normalization: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6156
   Why is that and how can i manipulate the data before XML generation?

My approach was to create a CollectionNormalizer and some other Normalizers to have the appropriate structure and let the XMLEncoder generate the XML.

Note that JMSSerializer is not an option here.

Comment: Can you post your code and the expected output? There is no reason that `ArrayCollection` instances aren't serialized (for instance API Platform does this).

Comment: You are right, ArrayCollection gets serialized. However i have a fixed XML structure that needs to be addressed and the Serializer is too hard to tweak. So i ended up building the XML via Twig.